# Change Color of JTabbedPanel side view

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I am having the following layout designed using JTabbedPane and want to change the color of the highlighted part. But I'm not getting a way to do that.
**My Question**
How to change its background color?
**What I tried?**
I've tried changing the `background-color` and `Foreground-color` of both JPanel and JTabbedPane but no luck with it.
I've also tried this while keeping the `Opaque = false` from the properties but no luck.
     `jTabbedPane1.setForegroundAt(1, Color.yellow);
      jTabbedPane1.setForegroundAt(2, Color.yellow);`

[image: this layout]
**Update 1**

```
 String[] tabNames = {"Signin", "General", "Call Rate", "Audio Device","tab 5","tab 6","tab 7","tab 8","tab 9"};

    for (int i = 0; i < tabNames.length; i++) {
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("<html><font color=white>" + tabNames[i] + "</font></html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);

        lab.setForeground(Color.red);
        lab.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        lab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        lab.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 22));
        jTabbedPane1.setTabComponentAt(i, lab);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.jTabbedPane1.getTabCount(); i++) {
        jTabbedPane1.setBackgroundAt(i,Color.DARK_GRAY);
    }
```

I've tried adding `JLabel` to change the size of the component where my tab name appears and then tried setting `setBackgroundAt`. Neither it works nor the `setBackground` and `setForeground` work on Label.
**My Look and Feel**

```
  try {

        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Settings.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the tabs, or the ‘tray’ where the tabs reside?

Comment: @VGR the tray where it shows the name of tabs like Signin,General etc

Comment: @VGR I updated the question with what I tried other than previously defined. Please have a look

Comment: Have you tried [setBackgroundAt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setBackgroundAt%28int,java.awt.Color%29)?

Comment: @VGR please look at the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic logic would be:

```
JPanel tab1 = new JPanel();
tab1.background( Color.RED );

JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.add(tab1, "Tab1");

JPanel parent = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
parent.setBackground( Color.GREEN );
parent.add( tabbedPane );

frame.add( parent );
```

Now the area occupied by the tab will have the background color of the "parent" panel.

If this doesn't work, then you have a Look and Feel issue.

**Solution**
the issue was resolved after changing look and feel

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 19.10 and using the default generated Look and Feel which is Nimbus

Comment: I just updated my question with look and feel. Please have a look

Comment: Well the code you posted does NOT do what I suggested. I don't see where you add the tabbed pane to a parent panel. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem (using my suggestion). Also, comment out the code that sets the LAF to Nimbus to see if anything changes. Then you can verify if the LAF is the problem. I don't have a problem on Windows using the default LAF.

Comment: After commenting out the Nimbus look and feel, it updates the defined colors. How can I identify the issue with look and feel?

Comment: It is above my knowledge level. You need to look at the Nimbus LAF code and try to figure out where the problem is. It is NOT an easy task to override the LAF code.

Comment: after using MetalLookAndFeel, it produces no issues and is working completely fine. Thanks for suggesting about the look and feel